# Using @ExceptionHandler or some other annotation that would work like a Spring 4.1 AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to configure and use a Spring 4.1 [**AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.html). According to the Spring team ([see relevant comment here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8995?focusedCommentId=101248&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-101248)) one will be able to configure an `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` either by with the `<task:annotation-driven>` or by implementing `AsyncConfigurer` as shown here:

```
@Override
public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
 return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() ;
}
```

Now my question is as follows: Is there another web-layer annotation similar to `@ExceptionHandler` that would work like a `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, here's an approach I've taken:

It's about async data imports so all classes are called Import...

What I did not do (yet) is the uncaught exception handling, but reading your post made me think about it and it should be straight forward with Spring-AOP wrapping the **Importer.process()** methods. This will not be global solution but it would be adaptable for a complete application by using a more generalized **Result** object.

The **Controller** uses the **ImportRequests** to get processing (or done) messages. The **Importer** itself is not removing the results from the map but this is delegated to the controller instead (A user is clicking delete). We also have a **@Scheduled** task which cleans up done results after 1 hour to ensure there are not left-overs.

So here's part of the code that the **Controller** is able to get import results during processing:

```
@Service
public class ImportRequests {
    private final Map<User, ImportResult> importRequests = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    /** Add, remove, get methods for current user omitted */
}
```

---

```
public class ImportResult {
    /** The done. */
    private Future<Boolean> done;
    /** The error messages. */
    private List<String> messages = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());;

}
```

---

```
@Service
public class ImportService {
    @Autowired
    private ImportRequests importRequests;

    @Autowired
    private Importer importer;

    public ImportResult doImport(final ImportForm importForm) {
        ImportResult result = new ImportResult();
        importRequests.addImportResultForCurrentUser(result);

        /* This is the actual Async call (process) */
        result.setDone(importer.process(result));
        return result;
    }

}
```

---

```
@Service
public class ImporterImpl implements Importer {
    /**
     * doProcess will import the *big* file and update the result object with the necessary messages
     */
    @Async
    public Future<Boolean> process(ImportResult result) {
        Boolean done = doProcess(result);
        return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(done);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

Original Text:

One possibility that I have used is the "@ControllerAdvice" on a class scanned by the servletcontext.

You simply create a method with the exception as a parameter and annotate that method with "@ExceptionHandler". You can even have multiple handlers for specific exception types.

The result of these methods are again handled by the DispatcherServlet, so you can render a view the same way as with request mappings.

Comment: Thanks Martin. The trouble is that an exception thrown by another thread than the servlet thread (as is the case here with an Async method) will not be caught by @ExceptionHandler.

Comment: That's true... What are you trying to do? Async call with user feedback ( even if an exception is raised)?

Comment: Ah ok. I have done something like that. I dont have the code, but I will check on monday. It involves having a singleton service keeping a map of futures per user. The future was based on a boolean only if i remember right, and kept messages of the long running process. Probably you can start from that, else on monday ;)